# Have WorldPay test our integration without customers seeing the site?

Tags: integration, cs-cart, worldpay

Basically, we have a site and a store already setup (not using WorldPay), but we’re changing to an entirely new website design, with a new store, using WorldPay this time (but using the same domain name as before).

Everything is all tested and ready on a temporary URL, so all that is left to do is have WorldPay activated and switch the domain over, but how can we give WorldPay access to test and activate our installation WITHOUT letting customers see the site at the same time (as we want to launch it on a set time/date).

The options from our perspective were:

1. WorldPay tell us the IP address they will be checking over the installation with, and we can limit access by IP address using htaccess or similar.
2. We change the URL temporarily to something like “/store38382882” which no one will know about, then once everything is activated, we would need to switch back to just “/store”. But from what I can see in the WorldPay docs, the URL you provide them with isn't easily changeable.

Are either of these possible? And if not, how is this usually handled? Just hoping for advice from people who've done this before!

Answer (score 0):

I put site on a sub domain, in the worldpay admin area, you set the callback URL and passphase specific for the sub domain.

Once you are ready for live, you just need to make sure that your settings also match up with the live configuration of your account on worldpay

for example:

live callback   http://www.site.com/worldpay/callback

Testing and demo   http://test.site.com/worldpay/callback

You should have bindings in your code to detect the Host URL  to pick up if its www. or test.  this will enable you to have settings for live and test without having to do many changes to your code, or worse, having two versions of the code base.

hope this helps